# Use OpenCV Threshold with Kinect Image

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, kinect

I'm trying to use the OpenCV Threshold with the depthImage retrieved by the OpenCV VideoCapture module, but I get the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument  in unknown function,
>   file PATHTOOPENCV\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp line 646

My code is as follows:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"

cv::VideoCapture kinect;
cv::Mat rgbMap;
cv::Mat dispMap;
bool newFrame;

void setup()
{
    kinect.open(CV_CAP_OPENNI);
    newFrame = false;
}

void update()
{
    if(kinect.grab())
    {
        kinect.retrieve( rgbMap, CV_CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE);
        kinect.retrieve( dispMap, CV_CAP_OPENNI_DISPARITY_MAP );
        newFrame = true;
    }
}

void draw()
{
    if(newFrame)
    {
        cv::Mat * _thresSrc = new cv::Mat(dispMap);
        cv::Mat * _thresDst = new cv::Mat(dispMap);

        cvThreshold(_thresSrc, _thresDst, 24, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        // Draw _thresDst;

        delete _thresSrc;
        delete _thresDst;
        newFrame = false;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start things off, **you are mixing the C interface with the C++ interface**, and they shouldn't be mixed together!

`cv::Mat` belongs to the C++ interface, and `cvThreshold()` belongs to the C. You should use [`cv::threshold()`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-threshold) instead:

```
double cv::threshold(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, double thresh, double maxVal, int thresholdType)
```

> Parameters:
>
> ```
> src – Source array (single-channel, 8-bit of 32-bit floating point)
> dst – Destination array; will have the same size and the same type as src
> thresh – Threshold value
> maxVal – Maximum value to use with THRESH_BINARY and THRESH_BINARY_INV thresholding types
> thresholdType – Thresholding type (see the discussion)
> ```