# Letter inside letter, pattern recognition

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to detect this pattern

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ghuaywtfdsb249j/test.jpg]

As you can see it's basically the letter C, inside another, with different orientations. My pattern can have multiple C's inside one another, the one I'm posting with 2 C's is just a sample. I would like to detect how many C's there are, and the orientation of each one. For now I've managed to detect the center of such pattern, basically I've managed to detect the center of the innermost C. Could you please provide me with any ideas about different algorithms I could use?

Comment: I think you can use the hierarchy of findCountors in OpenCV for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**And here we go!** A **high level overview** of this approach can be described as the sequential execution of the following steps:

- [Load the input image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16109992/176769);
- [Convert it to grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408961/176769);
- [Threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9471551/176769) it to generate a binary image;
- Use the binary image to [find contours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9334267/176769);
- [Fill each area of contours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966423/filling-in-a-single-colour-background-in-opencv/19989729#19989729) with a different color (so we can extract each letter separately);
- [Create a mask for each letter found to isolate them in separate images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20288616/176769);
- [Crop the images to the smallest possible size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317919/176769);
- Figure out the center of the image;
- Figure out the width of the letter's border to identify the exact center of the border;
- Scan along the border (in a circular fashion) for discontinuity;
- Figure out an approximate angle for the discontinuity, thus identifying the amount of rotation of the letter.

I don't want to get into too much detail since I'm sharing the source code, so feel free to test and change it in any way you like. 
Let's start, *Winter Is Coming*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

cv::RNG rng(12345);
float PI = std::atan(1) * 4;

void isolate_object(const cv::Mat& input, cv::Mat& output)
{    
    if (input.channels() != 1)
    {
        std::cout << "isolate_object: !!! input must be grayscale" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Store the set of points in the image before assembling the bounding box
    std::vector<cv::Point> points;
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::const_iterator it = input.begin<uchar>();
    cv::Mat_<uchar>::const_iterator end = input.end<uchar>();
    for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (*it) points.push_back(it.pos());
    }

    // Compute minimal bounding box
    cv::RotatedRect box = cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(points));

    // Set Region of Interest to the area defined by the box
    cv::Rect roi;
    roi.x = box.center.x - (box.size.width / 2);
    roi.y = box.center.y - (box.size.height / 2);
    roi.width = box.size.width;
    roi.height = box.size.height;

    // Crop the original image to the defined ROI
    output = input(roi);
}
```

For more details on the implementation of `isolate_object()` please [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10317919/176769). `cv::RNG` is used later on to [fill each contour with a different color](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html), and `PI`, well... you know **PI**.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    // Load input (colored, 3-channel, BGR)
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("test.jpg");
    if (input.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "!!! Failed imread() #1" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Convert colored image to grayscale
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(input, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    // Execute a threshold operation to get a binary image from the grayscale
    cv::Mat binary;
    cv::threshold(gray, binary, 128, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

The **binary** image looks exactly like the input because it only had 2 colors (B&W):

[image]

```
    // Find the contours of the C's in the thresholded image
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(binary, contours, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // Fill the contours found with unique colors to isolate them later
    cv::Mat colored_contours = input.clone();  
    std::vector<cv::Scalar> fill_colors;   
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        std::vector<cv::Point> cnt = contours[i];
        double area = cv::contourArea(cv::Mat(cnt));        
        //std::cout << "* Area: " << area << std::endl;

        // Fill each C found with a different color. 
        // If the area is larger than 100k it's probably the white background, so we ignore it.
        if (area > 10000 && area < 100000)
        {
            cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255));            
            cv::drawContours(colored_contours, contours, i, color, 
                             CV_FILLED, 8, std::vector<cv::Vec4i>(), 0, cv::Point());
            fill_colors.push_back(color);
            //cv::imwrite("test_contours.jpg", colored_contours);
        }           
    }
```

What **colored_contours** looks like:

[image]

```
    // Create a mask for each C found to isolate them from each other
    for (int i = 0; i < fill_colors.size(); i++)
    {
        // After inRange() single_color_mask stores a single C letter
        cv::Mat single_color_mask = cv::Mat::zeros(input.size(), CV_8UC1);
        cv::inRange(colored_contours, fill_colors[i], fill_colors[i], single_color_mask);
        //cv::imwrite("test_mask.jpg", single_color_mask);
```

Since this `for` loop is executed twice, one for each color that was used to fill the contours, I want you to see all images that were generated by this stage. So the following images are the ones that were stored by **single_color_mask** (one for each iteration of the loop):

[image] [image]

```
        // Crop image to the area of the object
        cv::Mat cropped;
        isolate_object(single_color_mask, cropped);        
        //cv::imwrite("test_cropped.jpg", cropped);
        cv::Mat orig_cropped = cropped.clone();
```

These are the ones that were stored by **cropped** (by the way, the smaller C looks fat because the image is rescaled by this page to have the same size of the larger C, don't worry):

[image] [image]

```
        // Figure out the center of the image
        cv::Point obj_center(cropped.cols/2, cropped.rows/2);
        //cv::circle(cropped, obj_center, 3, cv::Scalar(128, 128, 128));
        //cv::imwrite("test_cropped_center.jpg", cropped);
```

To make it clearer to understand for what **obj_center** is for, I painted a little gray circle for educational purposes on that location:

[image] [image]

```
        // Figure out the exact center location of the border
        std::vector<cv::Point> border_points;
        for (int y = 0; y < cropped.cols; y++) 
        {
            if (cropped.at<uchar>(obj_center.x, y) != 0)
                border_points.push_back(cv::Point(obj_center.x, y));

            if (border_points.size() > 0 && cropped.at<uchar>(obj_center.x, y) == 0)
                break;
        }

        if (border_points.size() == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "!!! Oops! No border detected." << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }

        // Figure out the exact center location of the border
        cv::Point border_center = border_points[border_points.size() / 2];
        //cv::circle(cropped, border_center, 3, cv::Scalar(128, 128, 128));
        //cv::imwrite("test_border_center.jpg", cropped);
```

The procedure above *scans a single vertical line* from top/middle of the image to find the borders of the circle to be able to calculate it's width. Again, for education purposes I painted a small gray circle in the middle of the border. This is what **cropped** looks like:

[image] [image]

```
        // Scan the border of the circle for discontinuities 
        int radius = obj_center.y - border_center.y;
        if (radius < 0) 
            radius *= -1;  
        std::vector<cv::Point> discontinuity_points;   
        std::vector<int> discontinuity_angles;
        for (int angle = 0; angle <= 360; angle++)
        {
            int x = obj_center.x + (radius * cos((angle+90) * (PI / 180.f))); 
            int y = obj_center.y + (radius * sin((angle+90) * (PI / 180.f)));                

            if (cropped.at<uchar>(x, y) < 128)
            {
                discontinuity_points.push_back(cv::Point(y, x));
                discontinuity_angles.push_back(angle); 
                //cv::circle(cropped, cv::Point(y, x), 1, cv::Scalar(128, 128, 128));                           
            }
        }

        //std::cout << "Discontinuity size: " << discontinuity_points.size() << std::endl;
        if (discontinuity_points.size() == 0 && discontinuity_angles.size() == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "!!! Oops! No discontinuity detected. It's a perfect circle, dang!" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
```

Great, so the piece of code above scans along the middle of the circle's border looking for discontinuity. I'm sharing a sample image to illustrate what I mean. Every gray dot on the image represents a pixel that is tested. When the pixel is black it means we found a discontinuity:

[image]

```
        // Figure out the approximate angle of the discontinuity: 
        // the first angle found will suffice for this demo.
        int approx_angle = discontinuity_angles[0];        
        std::cout << "#" << i << " letter C is rotated approximately at: " << approx_angle << " degrees" << std::endl;    

        // Figure out the central point of the discontinuity
        cv::Point discontinuity_center;
        for (int a = 0; a < discontinuity_points.size(); a++)
            discontinuity_center += discontinuity_points[a];
        discontinuity_center.x /= discontinuity_points.size(); 
        discontinuity_center.y /= discontinuity_points.size(); 
        cv::circle(orig_cropped, discontinuity_center, 2, cv::Scalar(128, 128, 128));

        cv::imshow("Original crop", orig_cropped);
        cv::waitKey(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Very well... This last piece of code is responsible for figuring out the approximate angle of the discontinuity as well as indicate the central point of discontinuity. The following images are stored by **orig_cropped**. Once again I added a gray dot to show the exact positions detected as the center of the gaps:

[image] [image]

When executed, this application prints the following information to the screen:

```
#0 letter C is rotated approximately at: 49 degrees
#1 letter C is rotated approximately at: 0 degrees
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect a so detailed response! Thnx a lot, you gave me bunch of ideas! I'll put them to the test!

Comment: The angle computation needs a little bit of work, but the rest seems pretty solid. I tested with other images. Please **up vote** the answers that helped you, and **click on the checkbox** near the answer that best solved your problem to select it as the official problem solver. By doing these things you will be helping future visitors!

Comment: the greatest answer I've seen in this website till now, by far

Answer (score 0):

For start you could use Hough transformation. This algorithm is not very fast, but it's quite robust. Especially if you have such clear images.

The general approach would be:

```
1) preprocessing - suppress noise, convert to grayscale / binary
2) run edge detector
3) run Hough transform - IIRC it's `cv::HoughCircles` in OpenCV
4) do some postprocessing - remove surplus circles, decide which ones correspond to shape of letter C, and so on
```

My approach will give you 2 hough circles per letter C. One on inner boundary, one on outer letter C. If you want only one circle per letter you can use skeletonization algoritm. More info here http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/skeleton.htm

Comment: Thank you very much, that's the approach I had in mind. For deciding which circle corresponds to a C, I though of using an OCR engine.

Answer (score 0):

Given that we have nested C structures and you know the centres of the Cs and would like to evaluate the orientations- one simply needs to observe the distribution of pixels along the *radius* of the concentric Cs in all directions.

This can be done by performing a simple [morphological dilation](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/imdilate.html) operation from the centre. As we reach the right radius  for the innermost C, we will reach a maximum number of pixels covered for the innermost C. The difference between the disc and the C will give us the location of the gap in the whole and one can perform an [ultimate erosion](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/bwulterode.html) to get the centroid of the gap in the C. The angle between the centre and this point is the orientation of the C. This step is iterated till all Cs are covered.

This can also be done quickly using the [Distance function](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/images/ref/bwdist.html) from the centre point of the Cs.